# What is the effect of Helium-based surroundings (99% Helium) on electrochemical gas sensors?

Tags: electrochemistry, redox, electricity, noble-gases

I am currently working on a project measuring gas composition of car exhaust. In order to dilute the gas concentration down to something electrochemical sensors can read, I diluted the sample with pure helium.

The following is true for these sensors:

> **Importance of Oxygen.** The reactions at the sensing electrode (*anode*) for some gases are as follows:
>   \begin{align}
> \ce{CO + H2O &-> CO2 + 2H+ + 2e-} \\
> \ce{H2S + 4H2O &-> H2SO4 + 8H+ + 8e-} \\
> \ce{NO + 2H2O &-> HNO3 + 3H+ + 3e-} \\
> \ce{H2 &-> 2H+ + 2e-} \\
> \ce{2HCN + Au &-> HAu(CN)2 + H+ + e-}
> \end{align}
>   Simultaneously, the reactions at the counter electrode (*cathode*) need oxygen molecules to complete the process:
>   $$\ce{O2 + 4H+ + 4e- -> 2H2O}$$
>   An inadequate supply of oxygen to complete the reaction will shorten the life of the sensors, hence the sensors will not operate properly.

Does this mean that doing what I intend is going to affect their performance and damage them?

Answer (score 1):

Aiming for dilution of the exhaust gases, you need a gas that is inert, i.e. does not react at these conditions with neither the gases present, nor with the metals present in in the [catalytic converter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalytic_converter) (if there is such device installed) and electrodes of the sensors.

Under this restraint, using a nobel gas was a good idea.  Yet instead of [helium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helium), that you still may use to spot leaks in the tubings, I would opt for [argon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argon), which is *much* cheaper per litre.  Note that at ambient conditions, its density as gas is higher than the one of helium and of air and has a slightly lesser thermic conductance.

Comment: Yet still, based on the spec sheet data above, that won't help with the bit about needing oxygen on the cathode. What is wrong with using dry air to dilute the effluent?

Comment: Oxygen may be either still present (Diesel engine, p. 6 at http://www.volkspage.net/technik/ssp/ssp/SSP_230.pdf) or may be added intentionally (and then monitored) by the design of the test engine.  At the other side, using dry air may to dilute the exhaust gases may render the analysis more complex: i) the then added oxygen may offer some combustion of previously not combusted material, ii) nitrogen may react at elevated temperatures to yield $\ce{NOx}$.

Comment: It would seem that a deeper reading of the spec sheet (and a call to their application engineer) might be in order for the OP.

Comment: @JonCuster I have read the sensor datasheets and they do not seem to provide any informaiton. Even the extract I added wasn't from a datasheet, but from a book. An when it comes to contacting them, I do not think that is possible since most of them are chinese copies.

Comment: @Buttonwood Do you think that there is enough Oxygen for these sensors to normally operate in the specified surroundings (95% Helium, 5% car exhaust) for both gasoline and diesel based engines?

Comment: @Erol From the spare information provided (OP), and as you say, the data sheet available, the experiment may provide an answer.  Do you aim for $\ce{O2}$? If so, modern cars perform oxygen monitoring regardless if based on a Diesel, or Otto engine; which may be seen as "there are sensors that by design may used on both".  A statement "The [$\lambda{}$] sensor does not actually measure oxygen concentration, but rather the difference between the amount of oxygen in the exhaust gas and the amount of oxygen in air." at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxygen_sensor for some of them supports this.

Comment: @Buttonwood What do you mean? Are you impling on testing the sensor in various concetrations of oxygen found in the car exhaust ie. putting the sensor directly in the exhaust and seeing how it behaves?                                                Nevertheless, I think I have found a way for keeping the sensors working fine and preventing any potential damage. After the sensors give me the measurments, I empty the sample mixture out of the chamber in which they are located and fill it with air for a brief amount of time. Will this be sufficient for the cathode reactions and their completion?

Comment: @Erol is the sensor you are using of the electrochemical type (e.g. two solid electrolytes with an air gap) as described on [Figaro's web site](http://www.figaro.co.jp/en/technicalinfo/principle/electrochemical-type.html)? It's frustrating when trying to read the data sheets for the current supply of the low-cost versions of old designs, and some of those (just for example [MG-811](http://eph.ccs.miami.edu/precise/GasSensorSpecs/CO2.pdf)) contain minimal and potentially wrong or incomplete information. Reading text books and older publications (the way you describe) is the right way to go.

Comment: @Erol [slightly related](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/302225/102305) although these are mostly MOS and not electrochemical sensors.